# Gaussian elimination with pivoting in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that will solve a linear system using gaussian elimination with pivoting. I am not allowed to use any modules either. 
Can someone help me out here? I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance :) :) :)

First i set up augmented matrix M, then i do the pivoting and row operations and finally i do the back substitution

```
def linearsolver(A,b):   
  n = len(A) 
  M = A 

  i = 0 
  for x in M:
   x.append(b[i]) 
   i += 1 

  for k in range(n):   
   for i in range(k,n): 
     if abs(M[i][k]) > abs(M[k][k]):  
        M[k], M[i] = M[i],M[k]  
     else: 
        pass  

   for j in range(k+1,n):
       q = M[j][k] / M[k][k] 
       for m in range(k, n+1):         
          M[j][m] +=  q * M[k][m]

  x = [0 for i in range(n)]

  x[n] =float(M[n][n+1])/M[n][n]
  for i in range (n-1,-1,-1): 
    z = 0 
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        z = z  + float(M[i][j])*x[j] 
    x[i] = float(M[i][n+1] - z)/M[i][i]
  print x
```

Comment: Not allowed? Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: Yeah dude, we can't use any modules. Can you at least tell me if I'm close haha

Comment: I think I'm getting mixed up with indexing and my loops after i do the swap

Comment: you should update your answer with the kind of input you're using for that function

Answer (score 32):

Let's make it educational as it is clearly your homework and explain the mistakes in the code, shall we? Maybe you can learn something in the process.

Assume there is the following matrix to solve:

```
A = [[3, 2, -4], [2, 3, 3], [5, -3, 1]]
b = [3, 15, 14]
```

Your initial code:

```
def linearsolver(A,b):   
  n = len(A) 
  M = A 

  i = 0 
  for x in M:
   x.append(b[i]) 
   i += 1 

  for k in range(n):   
   for i in range(k,n): 
     if abs(M[i][k]) > abs(M[k][k]):  
        M[k], M[i] = M[i],M[k]  
     else: 
        pass  

   for j in range(k+1,n):
       q = M[j][k] / M[k][k] 
       for m in range(k, n+1):         
          M[j][m] +=  q * M[k][m]

  x = [0 for i in range(n)]

  x[n] =float(M[n][n+1])/M[n][n]
  for i in range (n-1,-1,-1): 
    z = 0 
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        z = z  + float(M[i][j])*x[j] 
    x[i] = float(M[i][n+1] - z)/M[i][i]
  print x
```

As first you get an error, something about index out of range or something

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solver.py", line 32, in <module>
    print linearsolver([[3, 2, -4], [2, 3, 3], [5, -3, 1]], [3, 15, 14])
  File "solver.py", line 24, in linearsolver
    x[n] =float(M[n][n+1])/M[n][n]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How you can debug this? Print the current state of the calculation:

```
  x = [0 for i in range(n)]

  print "n = ", n
  print "x = ", x
  for row in M:
    print row

  x[n] =float(M[n][n+1])/M[n][n]
```

You will get output:

```
n =  3
x =  [0, 0, 0]
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solver.py", line 37, in <module>
    print linearsolver([[3, 2, -4], [2, 3, 3], [5, -3, 1]], [3, 15, 14])
  File "solver.py", line 29, in linearsolver
    x[n] =float(M[n][n+1])/M[n][n]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you count it correctly, you try to write to `x[3]` and access `M[3][4]` and `M[3][3]`. However, python counts from 0, meaning that the last element is -1 smaller than expected. Last element are `x[2]` and `M[2][3]`. This can be fixed by applying -1 to all indexes:

```
x[n-1] =float(M[n-1][n])/M[n-1][n-1]
```

Run it and....

```
n =  3
x =  [0, 0, 0]
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solver.py", line 37, in <module>
    print linearsolver([[3, 2, -4], [2, 3, 3], [5, -3, 1]], [3, 15, 14])
  File "solver.py", line 34, in linearsolver
    x[i] = float(M[i][n+1] - z)/M[i][i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Damn, another traceback! However, we're making progress, its on higher line now! When you look at it closer, you use `n+1` again. Originally `A` had `n` rows and `n` columns. Because you appended `b` to the matrix, there are `n+1` columns. Because of indexing from 0, the last element is -1 of the total columns: `n+1-1 = n` We fix it and there is code:

```
def linearsolver(A,b):
  n = len(A)
  M = A

  i = 0
  for x in M:
   x.append(b[i])
   i += 1

  for k in range(n):
   for i in range(k,n):
     if abs(M[i][k]) > abs(M[k][k]):
        M[k], M[i] = M[i],M[k]
     else:
        pass

   for j in range(k+1,n):
       q = M[j][k] / M[k][k]·
       for m in range(k, n+1):
          M[j][m] +=  q * M[k][m]

  x = [0 for i in range(n)]

  print "n = ", n
  print "x = ", x
  for row in M:
    print row

  x[n-1] =float(M[n-1][n])/M[n-1][n-1]
  for i in range (n-1,-1,-1):·
    z = 0·
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        z = z  + float(M[i][j])*x[j]·
    x[i] = float(M[i][n] - z)/M[i][i]
  print x
```

And when we run it, we get result!!!1!

```
n =  3
x =  [0, 0, 0]
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]
[6.4, 5.75, -0.75]
```

Just proof checking that it works:

```
3 * 6.4 + 2 * 5.75 - 4 * -0.75 = 33.7 (not 3)
2 * 6.4 + 3 * 5.75 + 3 * -0.75 = 27.8 (not 15)
5 * 6.4 - 3 * 5.75 + 1 * -0.75 = 14.0 (correct)
```

Hmm... Our matrix wasn't solved but there at least we have one row solved properly. The algorithm requires for the final step to have matrix in certain format, where most rows starts with 0. But that's not the case as you can see. Let's add additional prints to show the matrix as we compute it:

```
def linearsolver(A,b):
  n = len(A)
  M = A

  i = 0
  for x in M:
   x.append(b[i])
   i += 1

  for k in range(n):
   print "Iteration ", k
   for i in range(k,n):
     if abs(M[i][k]) > abs(M[k][k]):
        M[k], M[i] = M[i],M[k]
     else:
        pass

   # Show the matrix after swapping rows
   for row in M:
     print row
   print

   for j in range(k+1,n):
       q = M[j][k] / M[k][k]
       for m in range(k, n+1):
          M[j][m] +=  q * M[k][m]

   # Show matrix after multiplying rows
   for row in M:
     print row
   print

  x = [0 for i in range(n)]

  print "n = ", n
  print "x = ", x
  for row in M:
    print row

  x[n-1] =float(M[n-1][n])/M[n-1][n-1]
  for i in range (n-1,-1,-1):
    z = 0
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        z = z  + float(M[i][j])*x[j]
    x[i] = float(M[i][n] - z)/M[i][i]
  print x
```

And run it:

```
Iteration  0
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]

[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]

Iteration  1
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]

[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]

Iteration  2
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]

[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]

n =  3
x =  [0, 0, 0]
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]
[6.4, 5.75, -0.75]
```

As you can see, the row multiplication didn't happen at all! Let's inspect the state:

```
   for j in range(k+1,n):
       q = M[j][k] / M[k][k]·
       print "j=", j, "q=", q
       print "M[j][k]=", M[j][k], "M[k][k]=", M[k][k]
       for m in range(k, n+1):
          M[j][m] +=  q * M[k][m]
```

For the iteration 0, we get:

```
Iteration  0
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]

j= 1 q= 0
M[j][k]= 2 M[k][k]= 5
j= 2 q= 0
M[j][k]= 3 M[k][k]= 5
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]
```

Wait a moment, `q` shouldn't be 0! It should be 0.4 and 0.6! This happens because both numbers are integers and python provided result as an integer instead of a float. To fix this, change it to `float()`:

```
   for j in range(k+1,n):
       q = float(M[j][k]) / M[k][k]·
       print "j=", j, "q=", q
       print "M[j][k]=", M[j][k], "M[k][k]=", M[k][k]
       for m in range(k, n+1):
          M[j][m] +=  q * M[k][m]
```

Now we get result:

```
Iteration  0
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]

j= 1 q= 0.4
M[j][k]= 2 M[k][k]= 5
j= 2 q= 0.6
M[j][k]= 3 M[k][k]= 5
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[4.0, 1.7999999999999998, 3.4, 20.6]
[6.0, 0.20000000000000018, -3.4, 11.4]
```

Although it has a different output, we are missing zeros in the first column. Why? In place of 2, there is 4 instead of 0, In place of 3, there is 6 instead of 0. I know! You should subtract instead of adding multiplied row:

```
Iteration  0
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[2, 3, 3, 15]
[3, 2, -4, 3]

j= 1 q= 0.4
M[j][k]= 2 M[k][k]= 5
j= 2 q= 0.6
M[j][k]= 3 M[k][k]= 5
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[0.0, 4.2, 2.6, 9.399999999999999]
[0.0, 3.8, -4.6, -5.4]

Iteration  1
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[0.0, 4.2, 2.6, 9.399999999999999]
[0.0, 3.8, -4.6, -5.4]

j= 2 q= 0.904761904762
M[j][k]= 3.8 M[k][k]= 4.2
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[0.0, 4.2, 2.6, 9.399999999999999]
[0.0, 0.0, -6.952380952380952, -13.904761904761903]

Iteration  2
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[0.0, 4.2, 2.6, 9.399999999999999]
[0.0, 0.0, -6.952380952380952, -13.904761904761903]

[5, -3, 1, 14]
[0.0, 4.2, 2.6, 9.399999999999999]
[0.0, 0.0, -6.952380952380952, -13.904761904761903]

n =  3
x =  [0, 0, 0]
[5, -3, 1, 14]
[0.0, 4.2, 2.6, 9.399999999999999]
[0.0, 0.0, -6.952380952380952, -13.904761904761903]
[2.9999999999999996, 0.9999999999999996, 2.0]
```

Can you see those 0.0 at beginning of most rows? Let's proof check it now:

```
3 * 2.9999999999999996 + 2 * 0.9999999999999996 - 4 * 2.0 = 2.9999999999999964 (almost 3)
2 * 2.9999999999999996 + 3 * 0.9999999999999996 + 3 * 2.0 = 14.999999999999998 (almost 15)
5 * 2.9999999999999996 - 3 * 0.9999999999999996 + 1 * 2.0 = 14.0 (correct)
```

Computers have issues with floating numbers but the algorithm got us to the correct solution [3, 1, 2]

After removing the helper prints, there is the code:

```
def linearsolver(A,b):
  n = len(A)
  M = A

  i = 0
  for x in M:
   x.append(b[i])
   i += 1

  for k in range(n):
   for i in range(k,n):
     if abs(M[i][k]) > abs(M[k][k]):
        M[k], M[i] = M[i],M[k]
     else:
        pass

   for j in range(k+1,n):
       q = float(M[j][k]) / M[k][k]
       for m in range(k, n+1):
          M[j][m] -=  q * M[k][m]

  x = [0 for i in range(n)]

  x[n-1] =float(M[n-1][n])/M[n-1][n-1]
  for i in range (n-1,-1,-1):
    z = 0
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        z = z  + float(M[i][j])*x[j]
    x[i] = float(M[i][n] - z)/M[i][i]
  print x
```

Things to take away:

- Python counts indexes from 0, meaning that the last index is n-1
- Be aware of difference between integer and float division
- Print statements can help you debug the issues.